# How do I fix SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'': (421, b'4.7.0 Too many protocol errors (6) on this connection, closing transmission channel error Python?

Tags: python, email, outlook, office365, smtplib

I get this  error when sending  emails via smptplib in Python to a certain list

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'': (421, b'4.7.0 Too many protocol errors (6) on this connection, closing transmission channel.')}?
```

I'm using  Office365 SMTP details and a snippet of  the  code is below:-

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage
import getpass

ids = df['IDs']
emails_to = df['Emails']
namesofcompanies  = df["CompanyNames"]
sendfrom  = df["SenderList"]

date_7days = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
date_14days = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=13)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

email_pass = input() #Office 365 password 
context=ssl.create_default_context()
for i in range(len(emails_to)): # iterate through the records
    # for every record get the name and the email addresses
    ID = str(ids[i])
    Emaitstosendto = emails_to[i]
    companynames = namesofcompanies[i]
    tosendfrom = sendfrom[i]
    
    if my_files_dict.get(ID): #Looks for  attachments in the same folder with same name  as the corresponding record 
        smtp_ssl_host = 'smtp.office365.com'
        smtp_ssl_port = 587
        email_login = "xxx@xxx.com" #Office 365 email  
        email_from = tosendfrom         
        email_to = Emaitstosendto
        
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = "Received Emails between "+date_7days+" - "+date_14days
        msg['From'] = email_from
        msg['To'] = email_to
        msg['X-Priority'] = '2'    
         
        text = ("XXXX,\n"                
                f"xxxxxx\n\n")
        
        msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
        filename = my_files_dict.get(ID)#Files in the folder matching the ID   
        fo = open(filename,'rb')

        s2 = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
        s2.starttls(context=context)
        s2.login(email_login, email_pass) 
        attachment = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fo.read(),_subtype="xlsx")
        fo.close()
        attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)

        msg.attach(attachment)        
        s2.send_message(msg)        
        s2.quit()
```

On average, I will be sending emails  to a list separated by a semi-colon(;) of  about  8 emails  per record. This means  that for each attachment, I'll send to about 8 emails and I'm to do it  for about 70 of  such contacts. In total, that will be about  560 emails. Nothing gets sent  out I get the above error the moment I log in. On the contrary, when I try test sending it  to a list of  3 emails in the test emails column, the same emails go out very well. Can anyone  point  to where I may not be  getting it  right? I suspect either the list of  emails is too long or  is something with the email addresses thus the protocol error? Is this an SMTPlib limitation?

Answer (score 0):

What you specify in  `MIMEMultipart()` is what appears in the message header, but this is not always equal to the list of recipients. You can try to change `server.send_message(msg)` to `server.sendmail(sender,recipients,msg.as_string())`

Keep in mind that `sendmail()` requires a list of recipients, whereas `msg['To']` should be set as one string, so if your variable `email_to` is comma separated, you should write it like:

```
s2.sendmail(email_from,email_to.split(','),msg.as_string())
```

More details about `sendmail()` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by creating a list and joined all addresses from a tuple into a string, using a comma character as separator.

*family = the list of all recipients' email addresses*

```
family = [
'name1@example.com',
'name2@example.com',
'name3@example.com',
'name4@example.com',
'name5@example.com',
'name6@example.com',
'name7@example.com',
'name8@example.com'
]

msg['To'] =', '.join(family)
```